# LinkageError on instantiate Kotlin class with method notify()

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you can declare `notify()` method in class because `wait/notify` are not available for `Any` class. But creating instance of such class throws `LinkageError`.

```
class Test {
    fun notify(){}
}

//create instance throws LinkageError
Test()
```

Should it be the compile issue instead?

Comment: that's a bug, please report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, this indeed should be forbidden. Here's the relevant issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7174